# How to add local search on Google Map?

Tags: search, google-maps-api-3

I want to mark tourist places or restaurants on Google Map according to the need of USER.
How to customize the search?

Pls help, am some what new to Google map API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) may be exactly what you need.